# How to handle DTOs definition between different microservices using Java + Springboot + GraphQL

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql, microservices, dto

I know this question has already been asked, but I have a different scenario in which I have the following structure:

[image]

As you can see the front-end (UI) will always call a GraphQL API Gateway microservice that will redirect the request to different microservices depending on the functionality or data required. I simplified the graphic by drawing 3 microservices, but we have more than 30.

When I started working in this project, something that I noticed is that the GraphQL API Gateway microservice is repeating many DTOs that are already defined on the other microservices. As a consequence, this GraphQL API Gateway microservice is full of Java classes that serve as DTOs (with same fields, datatypes and no modifications), so basically, what developers have been doing was to copy and paste a DTO from user microservice and paste them in the GraphQL API Gateway microservice. The same pattern was followed for all the 30 microservices DTOs. Additionally, DTOs across microservices are being copy-pasted based on the needs. You may say that there should not be an issue, but whenever a microservice requires a DTO structure change, we need to change the DTO in all the other microservices.

Some approaches that me and my team evaluated were to:

1. Either create a common library exclusively for DTOs that could be reused by many projects. The only concern is that this will add some "dependency" and break the "microservices" idea. Additionally, I think this will not fully solve the issue we have since we would need to keep this dependency up to date in each microservice.
2. Use some sort of utility such JSON schema that will generate required DTOs based on needs.

This is something that I have been discussing with the team, most of the team would like to go for the JSON Schema approach. However, I would like to know if there could be something more efficient from your point of view, I took a look to some approaches like exposing domain objects (https://www.baeldung.com/java-microservices-share-dto), but I do not think this apply for the particular case I am talking in this post.

So, any suggestion or feedback will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where would you keep the JSON schema? The JSON schema is an implicit dependency. If you change the JSON schema, then you must also change the microservices that use the DTOs generated from the JSON schema.

Answer (score 0):

Consider having a loose coupling between the gateway and the microservices.  The gateway should not be aware of the domain model and behave like a true proxy.  It does not need to know about the DTOs.

With that principle in mind and assuming that your gateway implementation uses graphql-java, I suggest keeping the data fetchers in your graphql gateway very generic and returning an Object or DataFetcherResult or Map<String,Object> instead of DTO or POJO.  As an example, you can look at [GraphQuilt Gateway](https://github.com/graph-quilt/graphql-orchestrator-java) that uses this pattern.

The generic [ServiceDataFetcher](https://github.com/graph-quilt/graphql-orchestrator-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/intuit/graphql/orchestrator/datafetcher/ServiceDataFetcher.java#L25) returns an Object and it invokes a batch loader that returns the [DatafetcherResult](https://github.com/graph-quilt/graphql-orchestrator-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/intuit/graphql/orchestrator/batch/GraphQLServiceBatchLoader.java#L83). The data returned by the microservices is represented by [Map<String, Object>](https://github.com/graph-quilt/graphql-orchestrator-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/intuit/graphql/orchestrator/batch/GraphQLServiceBatchLoader.java#L299)

Hope this helps.